# Regex for matching a specific pattern only if it doesn't match other pattern

Tags: regex, perl, genetic-algorithm, genetics

I need to create a matching regex to find genetic sequences and I got stuck behind one specific problem - after first, start codon `ATG`, follows other codons from three nucleotides as well and the regex ends with three possible codons `TAA`, `TAG` and `TGA`. What if the stop(end) codon goes after the start(`ATG`) codon? My current regex works when there are intermediate codons between start and stop codon, but if there are none, the regex matches ALL of the sequence after start codon. I know why it does that, but I have no idea how to change it to work the way I want it to.

My regex should look for `AGGAGG` (exactly this pattern), then `A`, `C`, `G` or `T` (from 4 to 12 times) then `ATG` (exactly this pattern), then `A`, `C`, `G` or `T` (in triples (for example, `ACG`, `TGC` and etc.), doesn't matter how long) UNTIL it matches `TAA`, `TAG` or `TGA`. The search should end after that and start again after that.

Example of a good match:

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
AGGAGGTATGATGCGTACGGGCTAGTAGAGGAGGTATGATGTAGTAGCATGCT
```

There are two matches in the sequence - from 0 to 25 and from 28 to 44.

My current regex(don't mind the first two brackets):

```
$seq =~ /(AGGAGG)([ACGT]{4,12})(ATG)([ACTG]{3,3}){0,}(TAA|TAG|TGA)/ig
```

Comment: Just a small tip first, instead of {3,3} you can use just {3}, and inead of {0,} you can use *,
And you say it matching All of the sequence is a problem, what exactly do you want it to match?

Comment: You will have to give us example data. Most people here are software developers, not biologists. The meaning of your data likely makes no sense to us, and doesn't matter to solve your issue. Please [edit] your question and include some gene sequences, and show which bits you want to match. Thanks.

Comment: @simbabque I edited my question, hope it makes it clearer.

Comment: According to the pattern you gave, you could have overlapping matches. Do you want to find all matches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem here comes from the default usage of greedy quantifiers.

When using `(AGGAGG)([ACGT]{4,12})(ATG)([ACTG]{3})*(TAA|TAG|TGA)`, 4th group `([ACTG]{3})*` will match as many as possible, then only 5th group is considered (backtracking if needed).
In your sequence you get `TAGTAG`. Greedy quantifier will lead to first `TAG` being captured in group 4, and second one captured as ending group.

You may use lazy quantifier instead: `(AGGAGG)([ACGT]{4,12})(ATG)([ACTG]{3})*?(TAA|TAG|TGA)` (note the added question mark, making the quantifier lazy).
That way, first `TAG` encountered will be treated as the ending group.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCFPAz/2/).

Answer (score 0):

According to the pattern you gave, you could have overlapping matches. The following will find all matches, including overlapping matches:

```
local our @matches;
$seq =~ /
   (
   ( AGGAGG )
   ( [ACGT]{4,12} )
   ( ATG )
   ( (?: (?! TAA|TAG|TGA ) [ACTG]{3} )* )
   ( TAA|TAG|TGA )
   )
   (?{ push @matches, [ $-[1], $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6 ] })
   (?!)
/xg;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl essential regex feature, as opposed to plain regex like grep, is the lazy quantifier: ? following the * or + quantifier. it matches zero (one) or more occurrence of the character preceding * (+) token as the shortest glob match as possible

```
$seq =~ /((AGGAGG)([ACGT]{4,12})(ATG)([ACGT]{3})*?(TAA|TAG|TGA))/igx
```